# cp vs. cat to copy a file

Tags: bash, linux-kernel

`cp a b` and `cat a > b`, what's the difference?

In x86 install script of linux kernel's source tree (`arch/x86/boot/install.sh`),
both are used:

```
cat $2 > $4/vmlinuz
cp $3 $4/System.map
```

Why don't they just keep the same format if one is better than the other?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One more issue comes to my mind where `cat` vs. `cp` makes a significant difference:

By definition, cat will expand sparse files, filling in the gaps with "real" zero bytes, while cp at least can be told to preserve the holes.

Sparse files are files where sequences of zero bytes have been replaced by metadata to preserve space. You can test by creating one with dd, and duplicate it with the tools of your choice.

1. Create a sparse file (changing to /tmp beforehand to avoid trouble - see final note):

   ```
   15> cd /tmp
   16> dd if=/dev/null of=sparsetest bs=512b seek=5 
   0+0 records in 
   0+0 records out 
   0 bytes (0 B) copied, 5.9256e-05 s, 0.0 kB/s
   ```
2. size it - it should not take any space.

   ```
   17> du -sh sparsetest
   0       sparsetest
   ```
3. copy it with cp and check size

   ```
   18> cp sparsetest sparsecp
   19> du -sh sparsecp
   0       sparsecp
   ```
4. now copy it with cat and check size

   ```
   20> cat sparsetest > sparsecat
   21> du -sh sparsecat
   1.3M    sparsecat
   ```
5. try your preferred tools to check on their behaviour
6. don't forget to clean up.

Final note of caution:
Experiments like these have the inherent chance of rising your fame with your local sysadmin if you're doing them on a filesystem that's part of his backup plan, or critical for the well-being of the system. 
Depending on his choice of tool for backup, he might end up needing more tape media than he ever considered possible to back up that one 0-byte file which gets expanded to terabytes of zeroes.

Other files which cannot be copied with neither cat nor cp would include device-special files, etc.
It depends on your implementation of copying tool if it is able to duplicate the device node, or if it would merrily copy its contents instead.

Comment: So `cp` makes a file just like the original, while `cat` creates a new file with the same content.

Comment: Both tools operate on content, but cp (at least "modern" implementations) is aware of some specialities nowadays, like holes (old implementations of cat will run into that trap). There also are filesystems which are unaware of the concept of sparse files, for example HFS+ (MacOS) or FAT (MSDOS, USB-Sticks, etc), causing them to be blown up to their full size. So there are constellations where cp or cat won't make a difference in practice.

Comment: Btw, GNU `cp` has an option for controlling its behavior on sparse files; like, with `--sparse=never` specified on the command line, `cp` is as slow as `cat`.

Answer (score 7):

According to [Keith's comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30295/cp-vs-cat-to-copy-a-file#comment-40990), `cp` preserves some permissions, and `cat` creates the new file as `umask` indicates. So `$2`'s permission is not preserved that `$4/vmlinuz` is pretty clean, while if some strange permission is set on `$3`, `$4/System.map` will keep that.

Comment: is that the reason to attribute `cat` 's fasterness?

Comment: Is `cat` faster?

Answer (score 2):

Both have equivalent functionality in those two cases, but cp is purely a file operation. "Take this file and make a copy of it over there".

cat, on the other hand, is intended to dump the contents of a file out to the console. "Take this file and display it on the screen" and then have a ninja attack the screen and redirect the output elsewhere.

cp would generally be more efficient, as there's no redirection going only, merely a direct copying of bytes from location A to location B.

cat would be `read bytes -> output to console -> intercept output -> redirect to new file`.

Comment: `cat` won't really `output to console -> intercept output -> redirect to new file`, output file for cat can be stdout or a normal file, it'll just output to the file, as long as input is not the same as output.

Comment: `cat` has nothing to do with the console. Both `cat` and `cp` read from the input file and write to the output file. With `cat`, the output file is opened by the shell, whereas with `cp`, the output file is opened by `cp`; this makes no difference in performance. `cp` may be faster, but for a completely different reason: some implementations of `cp` try to guess the right chunk size for performance depending on the source and target devices; an implementation of `cat` wouldn't bother.

Answer (score 2):

It's really a matter of preference, IMHO.

There is technically no real difference unless you use the cp command with the -p switch to preserve file ownership/group. Otherwise, it's the same thing functionally. Marc's answer is much more clearly verbose though and accurate.

Comment: `cp` without `-p` does preserve *some* permissions.  For example, if the source file is executable, `cp` will make the target file executable, but `cat` will not.

Comment: Good point! So `vmlinuz` won't be executable whether `$2` is.

Answer (score 1):

Found `cat` here and there in some Makefiles/scripts which made me waste time as `cat` becomes interactive when no input file is given. One can also waste *real money* on build tools when stalled for a long period.

To illustrate with OP's example:

Let's assume `$2` and `$3` are empty shell strings (for any bad reason :\ ):

```
cat $2 > $4/vmlinuz     # waits forever
cp $3 $4/System.map     # returns an error immediately
```

I now tend to use `cp` or `install` over `cat` when possible.

Interesting answers and comments there, thanks !

Comment: Better yet, always check your inputs! :)