# What is the difference between (cp f1.txt f2.txt) & (less f1.txt > f2.txt)

Tags: command-line, file-copy

I know that both will copy data from f1.txt to f2.txt, but what is the real difference?

```
(cp f1.txt f2.txt)
```

vs:

```
(less f1.txt > f2.txt)
```

Comment: Related (and saner ;) is http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30295/cp-vs-cat-to-copy-a-file

Answer (score 6):

The difference is that `cp` is far clearer to humans.  That is one of the first things you should be optimizing for.

Using `less` in this way is so obscure, it's not really obvious that it works unless you try it out.  The other answer points out that it doesn't work - if your file contains certain characters, and you expect the command to work without user interaction, e.g. as part of a script.  This limitation is *also* obscure (at least I didn't think of it, despite having seen this behavior plenty of times).

`less` happens to be slower, one reason is it transfers data in smaller chunks.  Run them under `strace`, I see `less` chunks 1023 bytes (1KiB - 1); cp chunks 64KiB.

Answer (score 3):

`less` has been designed as a *pager* (e.g .with *next page* functionlity) for *text* files. As such it is less optimized for copying files than say `cp` (which has been designed to copy data), and might have a considerable overhead, thus lacking in performance.

For starters, `cp` won't ask you for confirmation when handling files that contain special (e.g. control) characters.

In your `cp` example, you need to run exactly *one* program (`cp`) .

In the `less` example, the `less` command actually only outputs the contents of the given file to `stdout` and your shell redirects the stdout into a new file, so you are actually running two programs (one output, and one input).

Answer (score 2):

- The `cp` variant is faster because it doesn't dump `f1.txt` contents to the screen:

  > ```
  > $ time cp f1.txt  f2.txt
  >
  > real    0m0.002s
  > user    0m0.004s
  > sys     0m0.000s
  > $ rm f2.txt
  > $ time less f1.txt > f2.txt
  >
  > real    0m0.009s
  > user    0m0.004s
  > sys     0m0.000s
  > ```

0.002 for `cp` vs 0.009 for `less`.

- `cp` can save some mode bits of the original file while `less` creates a new file with modes according to `umask` value:

> ```
> (...) each destination file is created
> with the mode bits of the corresponding source file, minus the
> bits set in the umask and minus the set-user-ID and set-group-ID
> bits.
> ```

- `cp` is shorter to type. Seriously, it matters when you spend most of your time in command line.

Answer (score 0):

Going on a tangent here since you're asking about `*.txt` files, there's one slight benefit of using `less`, which is to use its [pre-processing](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?less%281%29#INPUT_PREPROCESSOR) feature to "modify the way the contents of the file are displayed". A contrived example would be to output the contents of a compressed file to the output:

```
less compressed.txt.gz > uncompressed.txt
```

But of course, that can, and probably should, be better done by `zcat -c compressed.txt.gz > uncompressed.txt`.

Still, I'm guessing this can be practical for environments where the `less` pre-processing is standardized (check for the environment variable `LESSOPEN`, which usually points to a file `/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh`), **so that scripts/commands do not need to be concerned with *parsing* the input file into the target file**.

I've also found this [link](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/04/linux-less-command-open-view-different-files-less-is-more/) where it shows more uses cases. As mentioned above, check your Linux environment's `/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh` to see what are the variety of files that `less` can extract textual information from.